# Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

l am current working on a Mvc 4 application. My create Controller is as follows.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public ActionResult Create(OfficeCreateModels model)
{
    bool success = false;
    string message = "";

    try
    {
       if (model.Name.IsNullOrWhitespace()) throw new Exception("Unable to create this Office Name. The Type cannot be blank or spaces.");

       var company = models.Companies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.CompanyId);

       var officeExist = models.Offices.Any(x => x.Name.ToLower() == model.Name.ToLower() && x.CompanyId == model.CompanyId);

       if (officeExist) 
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Company '{0}' already has an Office this named '{1}'" .FormatWith(company.Name.ToUpperCase(), model.Name.ToUpperCase())));

       Office office = new Office
       {
          Name = model.Name.ToUpperCase(),
          Address1 = model.Address1.ToUpperCase(),
          Address2 = model.Address2.ToUpperCase(),
          Address3 = model.Address3.ToUpperCase(),
          Telephone = model.Telephone.ToUpperCase(),
          Fax = model.Fax.ToUpperCase(),
          Email = model.Email.ToUpperCase(),
          AccountType = model.AccountType.ToUpperCase()
       };

       models.Offices.Add(office);
       models.SaveChanges();

       success = true;
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       message = ex.Message;
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

My ViewModels and DataModels are as follows respectively

```
public class OfficeCreateModel
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Address1 { get; set; }
   public string Address2 { get; set; }
   public string Address3 { get; set; }
   public string Telephone { get; set; }
   public string Fax { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }

   public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
   public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}


//DataModels
public class Office
{
   [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   [MaxLength(50)]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [MaxLength(100)]
   public string Address1 { get; set; }
   [MaxLength(100)]
   public string Address2 { get; set; }
   [MaxLength(100)]
   public string Address3 { get; set; }
   [MaxLength(20)]
   public string Telephone { get; set; }
   [MaxLength(20)]
   public string Fax { get; set; }
   [MaxLength(255)]
   public string Email { get; set; }

   public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
   public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Agent> Agents { get; set; }      
}
```

When l'm running a code it goes on to create an Id and Name entities the rest of the entities return null. If l step Over, only the Name is returning a value the rest return me a nulls on ViewModels. May anyone help why my viewModels are nulls. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does the create view look like?

Comment: For every property you're assuming that they have a value in the view model by calling `ToUpperCase()`. This will cause a `NullReferenceException` when the string in the view model is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is `OfficeCreateModels` in the signature of the method `Create`? You posted only the `OfficeCreateModel` class.
2. What is the variable `models` in the body of the method? In the body of method, only the variable `model` is used (and declared in the signature of method).

I would have a look at the variables you're using. It looks like that you have a NullReference exception because of these variables not initialized.

Comment: OfficeCreateModels are ViewModels, and variable models is a reference to DBContext.

Comment: @Muzingaye Now I understood. Did you check if these variables are initialized?

Comment: all variables were initialised as private PMContext models = new PMContext();    as the tables to the below      public class PMContext : DbContext
    {
        public PMContext() : base("PMContext")
        { 
            
        }
        public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Office> Offices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Agent> Agents { get; set; }

        static PMContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<PMContext>());
        }
    }

Comment: @Muzingaye Ok, thank you! What is 'View' in the line `View(model);`? Did you check if this method is returning an object with non null parameters?